# A file (/usr/bin/sudo) highlighted with red in Terminal

Tags: command-line, sudo, mint

Anyone knows what it means when '/usr/bin/sudo' is highlighted with red in the terminal? This wasn't like this a few minutes ago

[image]

Apologies if this is a dumb question, but it's been a while I had to tinker with Linux.

Comment: Probably because it is setuid now, whereas it wasn't before. Compare with `/usr/bin/at` and `/usr/bin/crontab`

Comment: So what is the meaning of the red color? I do not have '/usr/bin/at', and the latter shows '-rwxr-xr-x' without the red

Comment: The meaning is that it is a [setuid](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Setuid) program. See the `s` in the permissions? And also that you have messed up the permissions of things in`/usr/bin/`. `crontab` is supposed to be `rwxr-sr-x`. Told you `sudo` wouldn't be the only problem you'll have.

Comment: And none of those are `chmod` commands, so the problem must have occurred elsewhere.

Comment: All I messed with is following these http://i57.tinypic.com/53sc9f.jpg Anyway, thanks a lot Muru for helping!

Comment: Sorry I might have made duplicate comments

Comment: Hmm. Oddly you marked my `pkexec` answer as correct, which means `pkexec`'s permissions were not affected (it is also setuid). You have never done a `chmod -R /usr/bin`?

Comment: I marked it correct because the setuid bit was not set to 's', and that is what I missed. I did not use pkexec just booted into the root shell. When I try your pkexec line it gives me: "pkexec must be setuid root"

Comment: Do you know any Linux literature which would explain what the original chmod settings should be? I am trying to restore the system and avoid a complete reinstall.

Comment: d@d-Aspire-M5~ $ ls -l /usr/bin/pkexec
-rwxr-xr-x 1 d root 23304 Feb 11  2014 /usr/bin/pkexec

Comment: That would be hard to tell. You could reinstall the packages, though: `find /usr/bin -type f -exec dpkg -S {} + | awk -F: '{print $1}' | sort -u | sudo xargs apt-get --reinstall install`

Comment: FWIW my `sudo` is also red, and I just confirmed that any file with the suid bit set will have this black-letters-on-red-background color. It doesn't mean they're wrong or dangerous, just showing that they are suid.

Answer (score 0):

That's the setuid bit of linux which allows to execute this binary with the user-rights from its owner or group instead of the user who calls it.
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Setuid